# Select filter - duplicated data

Tags: jquery, filter, fullcalendar

I have a problem when creating a Fullcallendar. I have

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar{(
    eventSources: [url:'http://localhost:3000/alldata']
)};
```

And this is working: I have a calendar with data from JSON on REST service.

But I want to filter the data by:

```
$("#filter").change(function(){ 
   //function which remove All Events Source // dont remember the Syntax, left it on another PC
    value = Here I get the value of current selected option
    $("#calendar").fullCalendar("addEventSource", 'http://localhost:3000/alldata' + value);    
});
```

When I filter it on the same month-page it works as it should and shows only data with specific VALUE. But if I go to prev or next month the data is duplicated!

I thought removingEvents will do the work but it didn't.

WHat should I do?

Comment: Try removeEventSource

Comment: Tried it. didnt help

Comment: Try using a function in events instead and then change what you give fullcalendar there. Call refetchEvents when you need to show new data

Comment: Note that the way you're doing it now should work but `removeEventsSource` should be `removeEventSource` and I think you probably need to specify what eventSource you want to remove. See docs

Comment: Ok, I remove it each time I  "Change" filtr.
It works that way. I have code in home-PC, syntax may be wrong here but it works the way I said

Comment: @Richard Hermanson
I will try the first suggestion of yours when I come back home. I will let you know if it helped, it may be it, we will see